# Magento shopping cart price rules apply to gross price instead of net

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is it possible to have a Magento (1.7.02) shopping cart price rule which is triggered on gross (post tax) price rather than net (pre tax) price? When you create a rule, the only condition which relates to price is Cart attribute >> subtotal, but this is net, rather than gross price.

If you create a rule to discount on orders over £50 and have a tax rate of 20%, then an order for £54 including tax will not be discounted, as it's net price is £45.

This problem is untreated to the tax calculation settings in the config.

I'm looking into programatically adding a new shopping cart price rule condition for gross price, but if I can sort this out via configuration then that would be my preference.

Comment: From the box it's not possible to have it on the level of price rule. I mean it should work with Tax Calculation configuration but in this case it will work for all discount types on your website.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade to 1.8

Take a look @ the release notes:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-and-ee-113-documentation-home

They have resolved this issue.

Comment: Can you highlight the section which resolves this issue? And what changes are necessary to achieve @mprototype